# separating blocks of lines based on value difference in a field with awk

Tags: awk

I have an input that looks like this (tab-separated):

```
line0   450
line1   500
line2   550
line3   600
line4   650
line5   1000
line6   1100
line7   1500
line8   1550
line9   1600
line10   1650
```

... and would like it to look like this: keeping together lines in which the jump in second field is less than 300 from equivalent value in previous line and separating resulting blocks from those in which jump is more than 300:

```
line0   450
line1   500
line2   550
line3   600
line4   650
XXXX
line5   1000
line6   1100
XXXX
line7   1500
line8   1550
line9   1600
line10   1650
```

Awk script that I tried but that does not work well as it takes lines in consecutive pairs and does not test the condition for each input line and the following one:

```
{
p=$0; coord=$2; getline;
    if ($2 - coord <= 300)
        print p"\n"$0
    else
        print p"\nXXXX"
}
```

Comment: And if the jump equals 300?

Comment: Don't use `getline` for something like this. Read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Will easily incorporate detail noted by jas in answer by karafka. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $2-p>300{print "XXXXX"} {p=$2}1' file

line0   450
line1   500
line2   550
line3   600
line4   650
XXXXX
line5   1000
line6   1100
XXXXX
line7   1500
line8   1550
line9   1600
line10   1650
```